# Getting size and lastmodified from multipartfile java?

Tags: java, spring, file

What is the best way for getting properties from ***MultipartFile*** in java like length, last modified, etc.?

```
@Override
public boolean moveToAWSBucket(RegionWS regionWS, String projectId, MultipartFile file) {

    //upload to s3 bucket
    try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentLength(file.getSize());
        // put last modified date?
        metadata.setLastModified();

        amazonS3.putObject(amazonProps.getBucket(), organizationName + "/" + projectName + "/", input, metadata);

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your attempted code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using Spring you can use the **getSize()** method.

Here is the definition.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html

And here some examples

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/

The last modified date value is part of the filesystem (Operating System), so you can not transfer this metadata with the file.

If you send the value in other field, this is not safe because any user could send whatever value they want. Another thing to notice is that the last modified date depends on the operatingsystem date. Ss if the user change its computer date the date that you recieve it's not real.

Comment: Ok, but what about lastmodified? Do I need to transfer it to File?

Comment: thx for answer... Is there any way to populate metadata with lastmodified date and send it to amazonS3? :-/

Comment: I don't know Amazon S3 API definition. I've never used it. But why do you need the lastmodified date of the file ?

Comment: needs of client/customer :P  I need somehow to get information about that MultipartFile...

Comment: You can use Javascript for reading file metadata. And then send the date to your server. See an example here http://wizard.ae.krakow.pl/~jb/localio.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method transferTo to convert it to a `File` object and then fetch required properties, because there is no method in `MultipartFile` class to retrieve `lastModified` information.

```
public File multipartToFile(MultipartFile multipart) throws IllegalStateException, IOException 
{
        File convFile = new File( multipart.getOriginalFilename());
        multipart.transferTo(convFile);
        return convFile;
}
```

Comment: Know this, but after I do this, converted file has only originalFileName... It doesn't know anything about last modified property..

Comment: It should have worked. 
`void transferTo(File dest)
         throws IOException,
                IllegalStateException`

Transfer the received file to the given destination file.

This may either move the file in the filesystem, copy the file in the filesystem, or save memory-held contents to the destination file. If the destination file already exists, it will be deleted first.

**_If the file has been moved in the filesystem, this operation cannot be invoked again._** Therefore, call this method just once to be able to work with any storage mechanism. 
Check if you have followed this.

Comment: When I transfer MultipartFile to File. All I get is pathname from constructor. Last modified property doesn't exist...